# Embed youtube videos with all the data like youtube website

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to build website (for my own, and for practice) that coantian youtube videos, I know there is a possibility to embed YouTube videos, but I want to know if there is another way to embed the videos, I want all the information of the video to appear, just like on the YouTube site itself.

[I want sonthing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caeZV.png)

[Example of a video embedded in a normal way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuuB5.jpg)

And that includes the title of the video, its length, upload date (or how long ago), preview of the video (when hovering with the cursor over the video), and I also do not want the YouTube icon to appear in the middle of the video image in any embedded video (before playing it).

I know some things can be done using the YouTube API (like video title / video length information), or using functions (e.g. preview gif) but it's a bit cumbersome, and in any case it does not solve the problem of having the YouTube icon In the center of the image of the video.

So I want to know if there option to enbed youtube video with all the details, or at least if there option the get of the sign of youtube that show in the center of the video.

Sorry for my English if there are any mistakes. Thanks in advance from everyone.

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: @johnh10 Yes. i want to know if there option to enbed youtube video with all the details, or at least if there option the get of the sign of youtube that show in the center of the video. Thanks.